# Why does my JSON post request end up as a hex value?

Tags: ios, json, post

I'm trying to do a post from my iOS app. The JSON I'm trying to pass is called `finalConvertedJson` and when I print it on the log, it looks like a good JSON object.

But when I post it using the code below, the web service receives the code as a hex value and doesn't know how to handle it. When I try the same JSON object and URL in Postman, it works perfectly.

```
self.finalStringJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.finalConvertedJson encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"this this: %@", self.finalStringJson);

    NSData* responseData = nil;
    NSString *urlString = @"http://10.2.176.100:9000/TestIOS?mobileData";
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    responseData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *bodydata=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.finalConvertedJson];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *req=[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodydata UTF8String] length:[bodydata length]];
    [request setHTTPBody:req];
    NSURLResponse* response;
    NSError* error = nil;
    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request     returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"the final output is:%@",responseString);
```

I'm guessing it's some sort of encoding issue in my iOS code.

I'm new to iOS so I may be missing something simple here.

Comment: can you show some log?

Comment: @mistyhua Since it's long, I pasted it on here: http://tny.cz/416bde8d

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on this line...

```
NSString *bodydata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.finalConvertedJson];
```

You are using `self.finalConvertedJson` but I think you intended to use `self.finalStringJson`. If so, you could just do this...

```
NSString *bodydata = self.finalStringJson;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it wasn't that line. I solved the problem by using a different post code.